# How to say "welcome back" in Korean?

Tags: greeting

Google translate suggests "다시 환영", but that seems to me to emphasise that the welcome is being given again, rather than that the person being greeted is returning.

Is there a more natural way to say *welcome back* than "다시 환영(합니다)"? I'm more interested in informal language if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 4):

Well, if you are at home and your parents (or some other 어른) are back home, you say "안녕히 다녀오셨어요."  But (I think) English speakers don't say "welcome back" in such a case, so it's kinda different.

Other than that, I don't think Korean has a good analogue for "welcome back".  I think the usual expressions for "welcome" are used instead: "어서 와", "어서 오세요", or "어서 오십시오".

- For some reason everyone translates "Welcome" as "환영합니다", but that's such a formal expression that I only remember seeing them on Windows booting screens and inside Incheon airport. :P

Answer (score 3):

If you want to mean "welcome" in Korean, you should write it like "환영합니다.", rather than "환영".

"back" means many different way in Korean, you should express exactly "returning".

"returning" is form of -ing(~하는 것), and "return" is "돌아오다".so, returning is "돌아오는 것"

so, "welcome back" is more natural in "돌아온(돌아오는) 것을 환영합니다."

Answer (score 1):

If you have been waiting for the listener who is one or more of your close friends around your age, you can say "잘 돌아왔어!" or use a rhetorical question "돌아왔어?" (or "돌아왔니?", "왔니?", or "왔어?")

If you did not know that the listener would come back, you can say "돌아왔구나!" or "(난 네가) 돌아올 줄 몰랐어!"

If you were worried that the listener might have had an accident, you can say "무사히 돌아왔구나!"

Saying "돌아와 줘서 고마워!", you can also thank the listener.

There are still other ways to use the verb 돌아오다.

---

On a side note, I disagree with the use of 환영하다 with a non-human object although some dictionary examples have such objects. Dictionaries define 환영(歡迎)하다 as the following:

> 표준국어대사전
>
> - 오는 **사람을** 기쁜 마음으로 반갑게 맞다.
>
> 고려대 한국어대사전
>
> - (사람이 오는 **사람을**) 기쁜 마음으로 기꺼이 맞다.
>
> 연세 현대 한국어사전
>
> 1. (**사람을**) 기뻐하며 반갑게 맞이하다. 격틀: 1이 2를 환영하다(1 : 사람명사, 2 : 사람명사).
> 2. 기쁘게 받아들이다. 격틀: 1이 2를 환영하다(2 : 행위/이념/조치…).

Only 연세 현대 한국어사전 shows with the second definition that 환영하다 can have the non-human object (someone's action, idea, etc.). Then, what do 환 and 영 stand for? A Hanja dictionary says the following:

> ...歡자는 눈웃음치며 즐거워하는 모습을 표현한 것이다.
>
> ...迎자는 이렇게 우러러 모신다는 뜻을 가진 卬자에 辶자를 결합한 것으로 길에서 **누군가를** 정중히 맞이한다는 뜻을 표현하고 있다.

In addition, the antonym is 환송하다; people use it with the human object only. Therefore, the object for 환영하다 needs to be a person or a group of people.